# Rearranging basic algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am starting to relearn algebra as I am starting to use more linear algebra at work. I apologise for how simple this question is going to sound.

The formula that I am working with is:

$$
x_{1}+2\left(\frac{-1}{5}y_{1}+\frac{3}{5}y_{2}\right)=y_{2}
$$

and I want to rearrange it to find

$$x_{1}$$

I know that the result I am looking for is:
$$
x_1=\frac{2}{5}y_1-\frac{1}{5}y_2
$$
But I just do not understand the steps to get there. If anyone could give me a walkthrough, I would really appreciate it.

Cheers,

Comment: The first tool, and one of the most powerful tools in algebra, is knowing
$$
\text{You can add the same terms to both sides of the equation}
$$
So for example, if you have $a=b$ then as well you could have $a+c=b+c$. This is the only rule you need in this case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The main principle needed to solve the problem is the distributivity of multiplication over addition.
In the equation, we have 2 times the sum of two things, the distributive law states that it is equal to 2 times one thing plus 2 times the other.
$$\begin{align} x_1 + 2(\frac{-1}{5} y_1 + \frac{3}{5} y_2= y_2)\\ 
x_1 + 2\frac{-1}{5}y_1+ 2\frac{3}{5} y_2=y_2&&\text{Using the distributive law}\\
x_1 - \frac{2}{5} y_1 + \frac{6}{5}y_2 = y_2&&\text{Simplifying }
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
x_1= \frac{2}{5} y_1 - \frac{6}{5} y_2+ y_2&&\text{Isolating } x_1\\\
x_1 = \frac{2}{5} y_1 -\frac{1}{5} y_2 && \text{Simplifying} \end{align}$$
And we’re done!

Comment: I’m not sure why the MathJax isn’t working well, and no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Don't worry, thank you for the answer. It makes sense even if formatting is trying its hardest to ruin everything. It was applying the distributive law that I was confused about.